# Produce a report of number of flights per day out of each city

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtVDp.png)

Can anyone help with this?
the best I could do is this:

```
SELECT To_char(Flight_day, 'dd-Month-yy') "FLIGHT_DA", 
Location_name, 
COUNT (FLIGHT_NO) "# of Flights" 
From FLIGHT_OCCURRENCE
natural join Flight F 
JOIN SERVICE_POINT SP on F.Destination = SP.Location_code 
group by Flight_day 
GROUPING sets(Flight_day,())
order by Flight_day;
```

Comment: For important details on how to improve your question see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZBo0.png)

Comment: Please don’t link to images, provide all necessary information in your question, preferably as editable text. Provide sample data for all your source tables and the result you want to achieve. What’s the issue with the SQL you’ve written

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT To_char(Flight_day, 'DD-MONTH-YY') "FLIGHT_DA",
Location_name,
COUNT (FLIGHT_NO) "# of Flights"
From FLIGHT_OCCURRENCE
natural join Flight F
JOIN SERVICE_POINT SP on F.Destination = SP.Location_code
group by Flight_day, Location_name
order by Flight_day ;
```